# How do we call an android path like com.example.HelloWorld.MainActivity?

Tags: android, path

I need to call the path of one of my views in my main_activity.xml, under the form "`com.blah.blah.view1`". For this I need to know its path under that precise form, and not the directory form ( `C:/.../.../view1.java` ).

Which leads me to this question I haven't found any answer to : how do we call a path written "`com.anything.myclass`" ?

Knowing this, I will be able to look for how to know the view "path", if someone doesn't tell me here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question is unclear...What do you mean by "calling a view in xml "

Comment: Well that isn't the focus of my question, more like the context. But what I mean is for example, in xml file `<org.yourpackage.scribble.DrawView android:id="@+id/drawView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

Comment: It is full class name (package name + class name). You can also find it as canonical class name.